# DMARC failure on forwarded SharePoint Online emails

Tags: email, dkim, spf, sharepoint, dmarc

I have a client that uses SharePoint Online but insists on using Gmail. Each user has a O365 account with an Exchange Online mailbox and mail flow/delivery options are set to forward all incoming mail to the corresponding user's Gmail address.

From Monday (08/10/2018), all forwarded mail from no-reply@sharepointonline.com (the default from-address of SharePoint Online used for alerts and workflow email) has ended up in the Spam folder of each user's Gmail account. The same happens when forwarding to a @outlook.com account.

It appears that the forwarded mails are failing DMARC so are being quarantined by the recipient mailbox.

Header:

```
Authentication-Results: spf=pass (sender IP is 213.199.154.180)
smtp.mailfrom=mytenant.onmicrosoft.com; outlook.com; dkim=pass (signature was
verified) header.d=mytenant.onmicrosoft.com;outlook.com; dmarc=fail
action=oreject header.from=sharepointonline.com;

Received-SPF: Pass (protection.outlook.com: domain of mytenant.onmicrosoft.com
designates 213.199.154.180 as permitted sender)
receiver=protection.outlook.com; client-ip=213.199.154.180;
helo=EUR01-DB5-obe.outbound.protection.outlook.com;
```

The way I understand it, DKIM and SPF are passing but DMARC is failing because the *header.d* address does not match the *header.from* address.

Is that about right? Is there any way around this? Is there some way I can "whitelist" the sharepointonline.com  domain so that these forwarded mails are no longer quarantined?

I don't fully understand how all this works but shouldn't this not be a problem as mytenant.microsoft.com and sharepointonline.com are both MS-owned domains?

Comment: Has the user been moving the email from Spam into Inbox? This might train Gmail that the emails are not spam even though they are failing dmarc.

Answer (score 2):

> The way I understand it, DKIM and SPF are passing but DMARC is failing
>   because the `header.d` address does not match the `header.from` address.
>   Is that about right?

Yes it is. The same goes for SPF, the `smtp.mailfrom` and `header.from` domains don't align.

> Is there any way around this?

I won't go into why on earth you'd choose a setup like this, with Office 365 forwarding everything to Gmail... To solve this, you might create a complex transport rule in Exchange Online to match for emails sent on behalf of SharePoint and change the Sender. I would not recommend it though.

> Is there some way I can "whitelist" the sharepointonline.com domain so that these forwarded mails are no longer quarantined?

I'm not sure how Google treats safe senders, but excluding those from mail filtering would shoot a hole in your anti-spoofing / anti-phishing defense.

> I don't fully understand how all this works but shouldn't this not be a problem as mytenant.microsoft.com and sharepointonline.com are both MS-owned domains?

Google doesn't care. The DMARC rules state that domains used for SPF and DKIM must align with the `header.from` domain.